# how call() on Array.prototype.concat works in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was reading about concat() method and came across this:

```
var arr = [].concat.call( ['a', 'b', 'c'], [1,2,3]);
console.log(arr); //prints ["a", "b", "c", 1, 2, 3]
```

I'm trying to understand how we got the output there correctly merged. So for `call()` method, we got to pass the "`this`" as the first parameter and other parameters as arguments to the function. So for "`this`" are we passing `['a', 'b', 'c']` ? If so, how come `concat()` is working like that?

What is the advantage of concatenating in the above way instead of

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].concat([1,2,3]);
```

Both yield the same output

Comment: I think that the code is intended as some kind of example; there is no advantage to doing that over directly calling `.concat()` in the context of the first array. The exact same thing happens.

Comment: Only advantage would be if you had an array-like object, such as `arguments`, instead of an actual array. But in the example you clearly have an actual array that will have its own `concat` method

Comment: @Pointy understood.. is ['a', 'b','c'] being treated as "this" in the call() method ?

Comment: @WildWidow yes exactly. The first argument to `.call()` says what to use as the value of `this`. The other arguments serve as the arguments passed to the target function (`.concat()` in this case).

Comment: @Pointy  So if we are concatenating in the context of the first array...why my first array is not being overriden?  https://jsfiddle.net/yajh25nf/1/   - I thought my array "b" would also print [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Comment: @WildWidow the Array API is not very consistent: some functions *do* modify the original array, but some functions return a *new* array. The `.concat()` function is one of those: it leaves the original array alone, and returns a new array as its result.