# javascript concat using call method

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm trying to concat two arrays in javascript using `concat()` method. I'm wondering what is the difference between these two cases

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(Array.prototype.concat.call(a, [4, 5, 6]));
// Result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

console.log(Array.prototype.concat(a, [4, 5, 6]));
// Result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I thought by using `call` method, as we are passing in `this` object as the first argument, it would change the array `a`. But it didn't.

Comment: `concat` does not mutate anything, it returns a new array. No idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Bergi   Thanks for your reply..in the mozilla document they used call() on a concat. I'm trying to understand what is the use case of call() here..when you can achieve the same thing without a call()

Comment: Which Mozilla document are you refering to? Please link it. `call` is usually necessary when `a` is not an array and does not have a `concat` method itself.

Comment: @Bergi  the last case in the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: @WildWidow you can use the prototype.call method if your unsure if the method has been overwritten on the array instance itself. Using the prototype method protects you agains the case where someone reassigned the .concat property on the instance itself with another implementation

Comment: @WildWidow: [And it's gone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat$compare?locale=en-US&to=1044998&from=1043826). Using `call` doesn't make any sense here (and calling `[]` an alias for `Array.prototype` is outright wrong). Hopefully [the `call` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) have some more meaningful examples.

Comment: seems like a similar question you asked earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36586596/how-call-on-array-prototype-concat-works-in-javascript

Comment: @JordanHendrix  I didn't understand it clearly..that's why asked again..why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Array.prototype.concat.call(a, [4, 5, 6])`

is equivalent to `a.concat([4, 5, 6])` (assuming `a.concat === Array.prototype.concat`, which is the case in your example where `a instanceof Array`).

> `Array.prototype.concat(a, [4, 5, 6])`

is equivalent to `Array.prototype.concat.call(Array.prototype, a, [4, 5, 6])`.

Given that `Array.prototype` is an empty array, both yield the same result. `[].concat(a, [4, 5, 6])` or `Array.prototype.concat.call([], a, [4, 5, 6])` would as well.

Answer (score 2):

`Array.prototype.concat` returns a new array. So `Array.prototype.concat(a, [4, 5, 6])` and `Array.prototype.concat.call(a, [4, 5, 6])` actually do the same thing. If you want to change the original array, you should, use `Array.prototype.push.apply(a, [4, 5, 6])`